# Issues with naming an instance of a class from an index of an array of Strings in java

Tags: java, arrays, class

Here's my code:

```
List<Player> l = new List<Player>();
String[] playerNumber = {"Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow" ,"Orange",
    "Black", "Purple"};
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++){
        Player playerNumber[i] = new Player();
        System.out.println(numberOfPlayers);
        System.out.println(playerNumber[i]);
        l.add(playerNumber[i]);
}
```

on the 5th line I'm getting the following error in eclipse:

```
- Duplicate local variable playerNumber
- Debug Current Instruction Pointer
- Type mismatch: cannot convert from Player to Player[]
- Syntax error on token "i", delete this token
- The method add(Player) in the type List<Player> is not applicable for the arguments 
 (String)
```

if I can't name it like that, how could I succesfully name them differently?

thanks in advance =)

Comment: That's a tiny snippet.  Why not include it here so we don't have to leave the question?

Comment: so you want to create an array of Players that each has it's own color?

Comment: @shaded, i just need a way to identify each instance. doesnt need to be a color

Comment: You have a few good answers below, but just to clear up any confusion, in your code do you want to be able to reference each player by the name or by a number? Such as Player currentPlayer = "blue"; or like Player currentPlayer = 1;  (granted neither of these will work but I'm trying to get a better idea of what you're actually trying to do.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String[] playerNumber = {"Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow" ,"Orange", "Black", "Purple"};
//...
Player playerNumber[i] = new Player();
```

What are you actually trying to accomplish here?  `playerNumber` is an array of Strings, not Players.  Can you say what you are trying to do in English?  We'll help you translate it into Java.

### Edit:

There are two ways you could "name" your players here.  First, you could use a map to associate a name with a player:

```
Map<String, Player> players = new HashMap<String, Player>();
players.put("Red", new Player());
Player red = players.get("Red");
```

Or, if you just want your class Player to have an attribute for its name, you can add that to your class:

```
public class Player {

   //...
   private String name;

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

}

//...
Player[] playerNumber = new Player[5];
playerNumber[0] = new Player();
playerNumber[0].setName("Red");
```

It's unclear to me how you want to use these names so I can't say one is better than the other.  In the above, however, it's probably better to use the constructor to specify the name, as in @Peter Lawrey's answer.

Comment: im trying to name the first player red, second player green, and so on.....but unsuceesfully i think....

Answer (score 2):

Another way to write this might be.

```
public class Start {
    private static final List<String> playerColours = Arrays.asList(
        "Red,Green,Blue,Yellow,Orange,Black,Purple".split(","));

    private final List<Player> playerlist = new ArrayList<Player>();

    public Start(int numberOfPlayers) {
        for(String playerColour: playerColors.subList(0, numberOfPlayers))
            playerlist.add(new Player(playerColour));
    }
}
```

EDIT:  To break this down.

```
private static final List<String> playerColours = Arrays.asList(
        "Red,Green,Blue,Yellow,Orange,Black,Purple".split(","));
```

split(",") break a String into an array of String using the separator provided. So it is the same as.

```
private static final String[] playerColoursArray = {"Red", "Green", "Blue", 
    "Yellow" ,"Orange", "Black", "Purple"}
private static final List<String> playerColours = Arrays.asList(playerColoursArray);
```

Arrays.asList turns an array of Objects into a List.

This line

```
for(String playerColour: playerColors.subList(0, numberOfPlayers))
```

if the same as

```
List<String> subList = playerColors.subList(0, numberOfPlayers);
for(String playerColour: subList)
```

the subList is view of the elements from `0` to `numberOfPlayers` So if `numberOfPlayers` is 3, you get a list of the first 3 colours. The `for` loop iterates of the elements in the subList so would iterate over the first 3 elements.

The line

```
playerlist.add(new Player(playerColour));
```

is similar to

```
Player player = new Player();
player.setName(playerColour);
playerlist.add(player);
```

However it uses the constructor to construct the Player with the name.  The advantage of using the constructor is that you can say a Player cannot be created without a name (with setters you cannot say that) You can also make the name `final` to make it clear it cannot change.

Comment: @bzupnick, At least two lines of code are originally yours. ;) What do you guess the lines of code are doing?

Comment: i dont undestand the whole.split thing. i also dont understand the entire 8/9 line.

Comment: @bzupnick, I have broken down what the lines do. Happy to explain in more detail if you like. You just need to think about it and ask.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?:

```
List<Player> players = new List<Player>(); 
String[] playerColors = {"Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow" ,"Orange", "Black", "Purple"}; 
for(int i = 0; i < playerColors.length; i++){
         Player player = new Player();
         player.color = playerColors[i];
         players.add(player);
}
```